# How can I set a new folder icon to the Volumes folder

Tags: macos

I created an alias for my Volumes folder under *Mac OS 10.14 Beta (18A353d)* and I'm really hard trying to apply a `.icns` to this folder. I just want to give it a different look, but it really does not work. With other files, it works.

Volumes folder ist under: Macintosh HD > Volumes

I tried giving myself Read & Write access to that folder and Alias (also tried symlinking it) but that does not help.

Comment: Why? The folder is invisible by default and actually none of your business because it belongs to `system`.

Comment: Because I want a shortcut on my desktop to it? So it is not possible? @vadian